# How to get correct residue of complicated function with exponentials and associated contour integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying to calculate the improper integral:
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx
$$
with $$ f(x)=\frac1{8\pi^3}\frac{x^2 \sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+e^\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$

The function $f(x)$ has poles at $x_0=\pm i \sqrt{1+\pi^2}$. I can then choose a contour of integration in the complex plane that includes either of the poles and goes through the upper/lower half plane.

For example, for $x_0=- i \sqrt{1+\pi^2}$ and choosing the contour to go through the lower half plane we have a residue of 
$$
\operatorname{Res}=\lim_{x\to x_0} (x-x_0)f(x)=-\frac{i\sqrt{1+\pi^2}}{8 \pi}
$$
and the integral becomes: $$I=2\pi i\cdot\operatorname{Res}=\frac{\sqrt{1+\pi^2}}{4}\approx 0.824227$$ but both Mathematica and a simple trapezoidal rule integration give a numerical result of $I\approx 0.0422885$.

Can anyone point out the error in the calculation of the residue/integral?

Comment: @mrtaurho Thanks for improving the formatting, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The function has branch point at $\pm i$.  You have not accounted for these.  Moreover, what happened to the singularities at $z=\pm i\sqrt{1+\pi^2(2n-1)^2}$ for $n=0,-1, \pm 2,\pm 3,\pm 4,\dots$ .  You have not accounted for these either.

Comment: @MarkViola Many thanks for your response! Any hints on how to account for the branch points?

Comment: Why do you believe that one can obtain a closed form solution by using contour integration?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a closed form solution to be honest, but my first naive (and wrong as you pointed out) attempt was promising... I'm now trying to account for the branch points; any advice is much appreciated!